# Idiom to say something beats something else greatly in a rivalry situation

Tags: idioms, comparisons

Say for example we are comparing the hotness of weather of two countries or cities. They are both hot, but one beats another one to a great extent. Lets say we are comparing Dubai to Death Valley. How can we say in short that Death Valley beats Dubai in hotness greatly? Something maybe in the form of:

```
Death Valley ____ Dubai in hotness!
```

But not necessarily confined to the form above, if there is a better way to deliver the meaning.

**EDIT:**
In Persian for example we say something like:

```
Death Valley is so hot, it puts Dubai in its side pocket!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are forms in which the property of interest is clear from the context; one can use this method for almost any property.  Optionally, to mention the property in the same sentence, add *Dubai is hot, but...*, or *Death Valley is so hot, ...* at the front of each form.

- Dubai can't be compared to Death Valley. (Optional alternatives: "Death Valley is so hot, Dubai can hardly be compared to it" or "Death Valley is so hot, Dubai cannot hope to compare.")
- Dubai can't hold a candle to Death Valley.
- Death Valley is in a class of its own.
- Death Valley puts Dubai in the shade.
- Death Valley puts Dubai to shame. (Mostly used for things that are good. Things like 'skill', not 'heat'.)

Here are some forms where the property being compared must appear in the phrase:

- Dubai is hot, but the heat in Death Valley is of another order of magnitude entirely.
- Death Valley makes Dubai seem cool by comparison.

Comment: I like all of your alternatives. But can we use them in other types of comparisons? For example comparing championship cups won by two football teams: "When it comes to world cups, Argentina can't hold a candle to Brazil!" Does it work?
I'm looking for kind of a general idiom. The Persian example I gave can be used in almost all kinds of comparisons.

Comment: @aligf: The rewrite of my answer hopefully answers your question?
I've made this community wiki, so everyone is welcome to add answers under the headings. (And, indeed, new headings entirely.)

Comment: For OP's exact context, I think *"puts Dubai in the **shade**"* [knocks all other alternatives into a cocked hat](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/knocked-into-a-cocked-hat.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's a single word, not an idiom, but *trounce* could work.  The word can mean *to thrash physically*, but it also means *to defeat decisively in a competition*.

- *In terms of heat, Death Valley trounces Dubai!*
- *Dubai is hot, but Death Valley trounces Dubai.*

Answer (score 1):

Triumphs over?

Exceeds or greatly exceeds?

Totally pwns?  ;)

Comment: "Totally pwns" is really good, but brings to mind MMORPG kind of rivarly between people! Is it used in other contexts, in comparing cities for example?

Comment: @aligf: Sometimes, but only (1) in (very) informal situations, and (2) between people who know that they are both familiar with Internet culture.

Answer (score 1):

The word I most often encounter in this kind of comparison is **beat** (*Coke beats Pepsi* in taste tests), and I wonder why you don't consider that even though you use it in your question.

If you simply can't stand that word, another possibility is

> **trump**
>   *v.*
>   beat (someone or something) by saying or doing something better: *taste trumps most if not all other factors when consumers choose food products.* [NOAD]

If you want to suggest that the difference is slight but real, you could use **edges**: *Death Valley edges Dubai in temperature war.* To suggest the difference is vast, substitute **slaughters**, **annihilates**, or a similar verb.

Comment: In re 'to edge', wouldn't that be 'to have the edge on'? E.g.

'(When it comes to temperature,) Death Valley has the edge on Dubai.'

(Or 'to edge out', but that to my mind suggests actual competitions, be they sports or business.)

Comment: @Esteis: "Edges" is a familiar verb used by the writers of sports headlines in U.S. media to suggest a close final score: "Chicago edges Cleveland 1-0 in 10 innings"

Comment: Ahh, so the expression has gotten shortened. I'd missed that development. Ta for the heads-up!

Answer (score 0):

@Esteis, Nice ones those! I would probably have said it like:
Death Valley is so hot that it puts Dubai right out of the competition.